# MongoDB Performance Test - Basic Understanding - Java

Tags: java, mongodb, performance

I want to check how fast the CRUD Operations are executing on a MongoDB.

Therefore I recorded the time with the following code:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
FindIterable<Document> datasetFindIterable = this.collection.find(filter);
long finish = System.nanoTime();
long timeElapsed = finish - start;
```

I am aware, that the FindIterable Object comes with "executionStats" and "executionTimeMillis":

```
JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(datasetFindIterable.explain().toJson())
JSONObject executionStats = (JSONObject) jsonobject.get("executionStats");
Long executionTimeMillis = (Long) executionStats.get("executionTimeMillis");
```

However I am a bit confused, I get the following results:

| start (ns) | finish (ns) | timeElapsed (ns) | executionTimeMillis (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 582918161918004 | 582918161932511 | 14507 | 1234 |

14507 ns are 0.014507 ms

How can it be, that the executionTimeMillis (1234 ms) is that much larger than the difference between the System.nanoTime() (=0.014507 ms). Shouldn't it be the other way around, since the System.nanoTime() does also need some time to execute itself?

Comment: I believe the Java code `collection.find(filter).explain(ExplainVerbosity.EXECUTION_STATS)` returns the document with `executionTimeMillis` (the total time in milliseconds required for query plan selection and query execution).

Comment: Also, your call includes the round trip time (the `timeElapsed` from your code) to the database server.

Comment: Yes, I know. That is why I am asking. `timeElapsed` should be larger than 'executionTimeMillis`, since it includes the time my code needs to contact the database server. But it is not.

Comment: When you run this code `datasetFindIterable.explain()` the `find` method code is already executed on the server, I think. You can try the code I had included in my earlier/first comment and see whats happening.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast reply. I have tried it. But it seems the other way around. If I add the `.explain()`-Part ( `collection.find(filter).explain(ExplainVerbosity.EXECUTION_STATS)`) than also my timeElapsed rises enormously. Maybe the `executionTimeMillis` is not the time of the `find()`-Method but more the time of the `explain()`-Method.

Comment: See [Explain Results - ececutionStats mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#executionstats).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, there are asynchronous and synchronous MongoDB Drivers available.

If you use an asynchronous driver, it could be the issue, that the

```
"long finish = System.nanoTime();"
```

command does not wait for the

```
"FindIterable<Document> datasetFindIterable = this.collection.find(filter);"
```

command to return with a value, therefore the time difference could be lower than the execution time stored in the FindIterable variable.

Comment: I use the Java Sync Driver: `<artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>`